# In a throw of 1 unbiased dice, what is the most probable sum of the numbers that show on the upper surface of dice?

Tags: probability, dice

In a throw of 1 unbiased dice, what is the most probable sum of the numbers that show on the upper surface of dice?

I know how to find the most probable number that appears on the upper surface of dice
By doing this
(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)......

Most probable number in this case is 7

But how to do the same in case of 13 dice?

Comment: Friendly linguistic reminder: "dice" is already plural and does not require an $s$ to be placed at the end of it.  "Die" is the singular of dice.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of dice, which include all consecutive numbers between 1 and 6, the most likely sum of multiple dice is logically going to be, due to symmetry of the probability distribution, the center value(s). For the example of two dice the possible range is 2-12, the center value is 7. The possible range would be: 13-78, in this case the center values are 45 and 46. For a detailed explanation see here:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3614/how-to-easily-determine-the-results-distribution-for-multiple-dice

Comment: It's true, but I have to say that "logically going to be the centre values" is to my mind hand-waving. Is there a simple **proof**? (I know a not-very-simple proof).

Comment: 45 and 46 are the centre values but how to choose between the two @Ravenex

Comment: is there any easy way to choose between the two @Ravenex

Comment: how you calculated the range @Ravenex

Comment: Symmetry of the distribution alone isn’t enough to decide that it peaks in the middle.

Comment: The range is the sum of the lowest possible values 13 (13*1) to the sum of the highest possible values 78 (13*6). There is no choosing between the two, both 45 and 46 are equally probable.

@LordSharktheUnknown I completely agree it's a little bit of magical hand waving, but given the posters question and a few other question posted by the user, I assume this is a "help with my homework" question and I think a rigorous proof would be beyond the scope. That is why I linked the other thread that is more thorough.